# A simple Stoch RSI and 50/200 EMA pullback strategy not generating any signals

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I've been ripping my hair out why this code isn't generating any signals since it's so straightforward.

```
`//@version=5
strategy("A Simple Pullback Strategy", overlay=true)

// Variables
length = 14
overbought = 80
oversold = 20

// Moving averages
ma50 = ta.ema(close, 50)
ma200 = ta.ema(close, 200)

// Stochastic RSI
rsiVal = ta.rsi(close, length)
k = ta.stoch(rsiVal, 3, 3, length)

// Buy signal
if (k < oversold) and (ma50 > ma200)
    strategy.entry("Buy", strategy.long)

// Sell signal
if (k > overbought) and (ma50 < ma200)
    strategy.entry("Sell", strategy.short)`
```

It should generate a Buy signal whenever the 50 is above the 200 and the Stoch RSI is below 20 and a Sell signal whenever the 50 is below the 200 with the Stoch RSI above 80. When browsing the chart with the EMAs and Stoch RSI open I'm seeing several points off the bat that should be a signal but nada, nothing, zero. Changing the Stoch RSI params to 30/70 does nothing either even though - again - I can see several potential signals that should be there that aren't. Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: It looks like your long condition never becomes `true` and you are stuck in a short position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

plot "K" for debug.

seems to be wrong

compare to Stochastic RSI by Bullit-in Script Library

Try this:

```
k = ta.sma(ta.stoch(rsiVal, rsiVal, rsiVal, length), 3)
```